# XDT Transform not working for applicationHost.xdt on Azure - Environment variables are ignored

Tags: azure-devops, environment-variables, kudu, xdt-transform

It seems like environment variables are being ignored in my xdt transform for applicationHost.

I've created the following file `applicationHost.xdt` on azure in the `\home\site` folder.  It does NOT perform the transform on applicationHost.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">>
  <system.applicationHost>
    <applicationPools>
      <add name="%WEBSITE_SITE_NAME%" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
        <recycling disallowOverlappingRotation="true" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
      </add>
      <add name="%WEBSITE_IIS_SITE_NAME%" xdt:Locator="Match(name)">
        <recycling disallowOverlappingRotation="true" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
      </add>
    </applicationPools>
  </system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

**If I adjust the %WEBSITE_SITE_NAME% to say "dev-mysitename.com" the transforms work properly**.

Why are the Environment variables not working properly?  I need this to work so my different environments will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Environment Variables like this.  Its just not possible.